# Are there published algorithms for on-line creation of AVL trees from ordered streams?

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, online-algorithms, binary-trees

Given an ordered stream of *n* items (*n* unknown in advance), it is well-known how to construct a red-black tree from them in O(*n*)-time.  More specifically this is possible using only O(log *n*) additional storage, and only O(log *n*)-time after then *end-of-stream* is discovered.  The technique involves pennants and the 1-2 binary representation of *n*.

The technique needs to be modified for AVL trees, and I haven't seen referneces to an on-line algorithm for creating AVL trees.  Does anyone know of such a published algorithm?

Comment: Do you have a citation for the claim about red-black trees? Do the items arrive in sorted order?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly and the elements arrive in sorted order, I believe the usual bottom-up AVL tree insertion algorithm meets your criteria. In particular, insert-only AVL trees have $O(1)$ amortized (and $O(\lg n)$ worst-case) update time. Simply maintain a pointer to the last element of the tree and perform each insertion at that location.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I was thinking trees with no parent link, but I suppose that I can maintain a separate linked list of pointers to the the right spine.

Comment: Or you can keep only reversed pointers (child points to parent) during the  creation of the tree, then reverse them when you're done.